# mysql index on derived table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate MATCH() AGAINST() scores from UNIFIED QUERY not FOR EACH TABLE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/calculate-match-against-scores-from-unified-query-not-for-each-table)

I want to have a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on `data` name in the base SELECT that selects data from another SELECT which unions several tables.

```
SELECT `data` FROM SELECT (
  SELECT `name` as `data` FROM `names`
  UNION SELECT `title` as `data` FROM `titles`
) as `search`
```

I want `data` to have a FULLTEXT INDEX

Comment: Why not define an index on the relevant columns of the base tables?

Comment: `name` and `title` are fulltext indexes

Comment: Those are table columns and not indexes, but never mind, I think I got it: there are fulltext indexes defined on `name` and `title`.  Then what is the question?

Comment: Okay, columns `name` and `title` are indexed as FULLTEXT. I want `data` to have a FULLTEXT index as well. But there won't be such column as `data` in phpmyadmin to make it FULLTEXT in traditional way. 

Question is HOW TO MAKE `data` indexed as FULLTEXT

Comment: You can't do that, unless you create a table with the unioned data.  But having indexes on both tables, why would you need that?

Comment: I'm making a search. I already tried making a temporary table for this but without fortune; MATCH() AGAINST() on this new table returns zero results because of "50% rule".

Comment: OK.  Then what is your actual query?  Without a `WHERE` clause indexes are often useless.

Comment: Please take a look here, I asked for help at StackOverflow as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914087/calculate-match-against-scores-from-unified-query-not-for-each-table

Answer (score 0):

What is your requirement? we cannot index "data" as it is not a column in table, It can defined with multiple columns within one table .

Few things to be considered while using Fulltext.
Its only supported for MyISAM engine,
You can also set few variables "ft_min_word_len" and "ft_max_word_len" to search,
Some stopwords are ignored we can set change values at "ft_stopword_file", and 
Its not case sensitive search.