# Calculate MATCH() AGAINST() scores from UNIFIED QUERY not FOR EACH TABLE

Tags: mysql, php, full-text-search

I am trying to have a score for entire section of SELECT statements

```
SELECT *,MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table1` WHERE MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword')
UNION
SELECT *,MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table2` WHERE MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword')
UNION
SELECT *,MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table3` WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword')
```

In such case scores are per table + they are not ordered by relevance

But I tried this method, which is working but is not worth of production

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table1` WHERE MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword')
    UNION
    SELECT *,MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table2` WHERE MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword')
    UNION
    SELECT *,MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table3` WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword')
) as `combined` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Above code is disliked because scores there are per table, they are joined and ordered. A bad approach.

So I tried to `MATCH() AGAINST()` for `data` in TOP LEVEL SELECT as well this. (DIDN'T WORK)

```
SELECT *,MATCH(`data`) AGAINST('keyword') as `good_score` FROM (
        SELECT *,`result` as `data`,MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table1` WHERE MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword')
        UNION
        SELECT *,`content` as `data`,MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table2` WHERE MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword')
        UNION
        SELECT *,`text` as `data`,MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword') as `score` FROM `table3` WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword')
    ) as `combined` ORDER BY `good_score` DESC
```

Above statement is perfect for me, but it does not work because `data` column is created on-the-fly and it does not support to have a FULLTEXT INDEX.

My question is how to proceed to get my engine working.

- Can you somehow make `data` a FULLTEXT
- Is there any way to make it work other than IN BOOLEAN MODE that does not support scores
- Is there an approach to this entire topic that would make it work? Creating a temporary table does not solves this, 50% rule of MATCH() AGAINST() makes a query return 0 results, but there are many
- Maybe there is a something little that I miss?
- Creating a VIEW does not work either, MySQL does not support INDEX-es on VIEWs.
- Maybe it is a good idea to use IN BOOLEAN MODE and create scoring manually?

I have been working for this issue for more than two days. So I kindly ask for some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could record the following from the three(3) tables

- table name
- the column from the table name
- FULLTEXT index on the column

Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS combined_data;
CREATE TABLE combined_data
(
    source_table VARCHAR(64),
    source_id INT NOT NULL,
    data TEXT NOT NULL,
    FULLTEXT (data)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
--
ALTER TABLE combined_data DISABLE KEYS;
--
INSERT INTO combined_data (source_table,source_id,data) VALUES
SELECT 'table1',id,`result` FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`result`) AGAINST('keyword');
--
INSERT INTO combined_data (source_table,source_id,data) VALUES
SELECT 'table2',id,`content` FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`content`) AGAINST('keyword');
--
INSERT INTO combined_data (source_table,source_id,data) VALUES
SELECT 'table3',id,`text` FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('keyword');
--
ALTER TABLE combined_data ENABLE KEYS;
```

Now you can run a single query against the one table

```
SELECT *,MATCH(`data`) AGAINST('keyword') as `good_score`
FROM combined_data
ORDER BY `good_score` DESC;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I have done similar thing before and it did not work. This one does not work either. Final SELECT from combined_data as good_score with MATCH() and AGAINST() gives a 0 result. I researched about this issue and found out that NON IN BOOLEAN MODE applies 50% rule, which by its nature somehow ignores results from one table when there is some mathematical relation with 50% of results. Still, thank you for suggestion, but I would like to hear some other ideas. Thanks again.